# Repeater Paging Custom Link Format

Tags: c#, pagination, repeater

I'm implementing repeater paging with a pagedatasource and I'm trying to format the links.

I'd like to creating something like this:

```
<< < 3 4 ***5*** 6 7 > >>
// Where 5 is the current page
```

This isn't that difficult of a task, but its probably been done already, and as such I don't really want to have to do it.  Anybody know of any custom pagin resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AspNetPager : http://aspnetpager.codeplex.com/ , it can be configured to work in a number of different ways.

Sample pages are here : http://en.webdiyer.com/AspNetPagerDemo/